# generic "There is a problem with your connection" error in CartoDB

Tags: carto, visualisation, web

I changed the cartoCSS for a visualization, but in a pretty straightforward way (fyi: changed some numerical cutoffs to other numbers, did not touch anything else). I am getting a "There is a problem with your connection" error on the visualization ever since, for many hours now, in multiple browsers.

Please let me know if there is anything to do about this apart from some deep plumbing only tech support can do. CartoDB staff is very helpful, but the turnaround because of the time zone difference with Madrid is getting frustrating.

Here is the new piece of cartoCSS:

```
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 15530191054167961601] {
marker-width: 25.0;
marker-fill: #850200;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 226926540] {
marker-width: 23.3;
marker-fill: #B10026;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 87005948] {
marker-width: 21.7;
marker-fill: #F11810;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 46218709] {
marker-width: 20.0;
marker-fill: #FC4E2A;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 27412874] {
marker-width: 18.3;
marker-fill: #FD8D3C;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 18665512] {
marker-width: 16.7;
marker-fill: #FF9900;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 12041280] {
marker-width: 15.0;
marker-fill: #FFA300;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 7283027] {
marker-width: 13.3;
marker-fill: #FFCC00;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <=  3711385] {
marker-width: 11.7;
marker-fill: #fed976;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 1316117] {
marker-width: 10.0;
marker-fill: #FFFFB2;
}
```

And here is the old one:

```
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 88302118874.01] {
   marker-fill: #d73027;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 83885841] {
   marker-fill: #f79272;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 32596503] {
   marker-fill: #fed6b0;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 17639686] {
   marker-fill: #fff2cc;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 9809490] {
   marker-fill: #d2ecb4;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 4741029] {
   marker-fill: #8cce8a;
}
#location_of_winners25mb [ hufvalue <= 1592812] {
   marker-fill: #1a9850;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the cartoCSS back? Showing the before-and-after might help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I have no backup of the previous state...

Comment: Try checking the very top of the file for a stray character.

Comment: Otherwise, you've got to give us something to go on. Right now, its "I changed something unrelated and now its broken". Think about what you can tell us. Perhaps a sample of what you changed it to, and what you think it was. If it was a simple change, you could at least try some testing.

Comment: I understand that it is weird, but I am still not sure what I could give you. Why is it obvious that none of you encountered any similar error before? E.g. you could say that this can happen irrespective of the code being erroneous but something getting stuck that needs a restart…

Comment: @BradHards Thanks again, I found the old examples, see the edits!

Comment: I don't see an answer to "Does it work if you change the cartoCSS back?" With no information, its almost impossible to tell if your problem is the same as anyone else's problem.

Comment: change 15530191054167961601 by 15530191054167961601.1 (not .0), it's a problem with big numbers and cartocss (i'm guessing)

Comment: @javisantana Thanks, that does not work. I am puzzled by outlier too, but would still put it on the map for now and think about cleaning the data later. Can I use anything else but the maximum as a cutoff? Can't I just apply that style for all rows (as ensuing specification will override this setting anyway for the lines below the other cutoffs)?

Comment: OK, I killed the condition for the maximum, and everything loads as expected. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the top value, 15530191054167961601. It is bigger than allowable numbers in CartoCSS expressions. Do you really have values in the quintillion?